# TFS is wonky after server move

Tags: sql-server-2008, team-foundation-server

We did a server move a while back and ever since then we have been having a weird "error" happen repeatedly.  In a nutshell, when you first request connection (via VS.NET, TFS Admin Console or Web Site) it fails with a DB timeout.  Then, just hit refresh and everything is working fine.  I looked in the Service logs and found this:

> TF53010: The following error has occurred in a Team Foundation component or extension:
>   Date (UTC): 7/22/2010 10:54:21 PM
>   Machine: WEB2
>   Application Domain: /LM/W3SVC/8080/ROOT/tfs-1-129243128405943147
>   Assembly: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; v2.0.50727
>   Service Host:
>   Process Details:
>     Process Name: w3wp
>     Process Id: 2068
>     Thread Id: 3556
>     Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
>
> Detailed Message: Application Request Processing Started
>
> Server Version = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>   Service Account = NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
>   Machine Name = WEB2
>
> Exception Message: TF246018: The database operation exceeded the timeout limit and has been cancelled. Verify that the parameters of the operation are correct. (type DatabaseOperationTimeoutException)

It is driving me nuts and I am wondering if anyone else has run into this behavior.  I've checked everything I would normally check and nothing is fixing this behavior.  Any ideas?

---

NOTE:  I am in trying to add a new team project collection in the TFS Admin Console -> [MachineName]/Application Teir/Team Project Collections.  Nothing is listing in the Admin Console and it is perpetually in "Loading..." mode.  WTF?

Comment: Are there any other messages in the event log, or in the IIS logs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending a couple days on the phone with MS Product Support on this we finally have it working.

- Reinstall TFS on the App Server
- Go through IIS and found app pools were not set right, changed back to f/x 2.0 classic
- Database machine's firewall was not allowing TCP connections on the correct port to SQL Server (hence the not connecting first time, then it went to named pipes and connected - but TFS wants TCP connections)

These were the main culprits.  We even went through all the security accounts and those ended up having the right permissions so were more of a red herring to chase.

There is a [tool for moving TFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) - use it!  ;)